# How to change group permissions in sharepoint 2013 using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, permissions, roles

I have a group "Visitors" with Contribute permission and I want to change permission to Read, programmatically. I don't have problem with adding new permission to the group, but I don't know how to remove old permission.

How to change this code to remove permission Contribute and add permission Read?

```
SPWeb root = site.RootWeb;
SPGroup group = root.SiteGroups["Visitors"];  
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = root.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
root.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
root.Update();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to:

- add `Reader` permission Level to the group
- remove `Contribute` permission Level from the group

Example:

```
SPWeb root = site.RootWeb;
SPGroup group = root.SiteGroups[groupName];

SPRoleDefinition contributeRoleDef = root.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
SPRoleDefinition readerRoleDef = root.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
SPRoleAssignment groupRoleAssignments = root.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(group);
groupRoleAssignments.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(contributeRoleDef);
groupRoleAssignments.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(readerRoleDef);
groupRoleAssignments.Update();
```